# read xml file with multiple elements to a list in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

Here is my xml file called wfXml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<webformname>
    <wbfrm>
        <wfname>WebForm1</wfname>
        <wfrm>WebForm1.aspx</wfrm>
    </wbfrm>
    <wbfrm>
        <wfname>WebForm2</wfname>
        <wfrm>WebForm2.aspx</wfrm>
    </wbfrm>        
    <wbfrm>
        <wfname>WebForm3</wfname>
        <wfrm>WebForm3.aspx</wfrm>
    </wbfrm>
    <wbfrm>
        <wfname>WebForm4</wfname>
        <wfrm>WebForm4.aspx</wfrm>
    </wbfrm>
    <wbfrm>
        <wfname>WebForm5</wfname>
        <wfrm>WebForm5.aspx</wfrm>
    </wbfrm>
    <wbfrm>
        <wfname>WebForm6</wfname>
        <wfrm>WebForm6.aspx</wfrm>
    </wbfrm>
    <wbfrm>
        <wfname>WebForm7</wfname>
        <wfrm>WebForm7.aspx</wfrm>
    </wbfrm>
    <wbfrm>
        <wfname>WebForm8</wfname>
        <wfrm>WebForm8.aspx</wfrm>
    </wbfrm>
    <wbfrm>
        <wfname>WebForm9</wfname>
        <wfrm>WebForm9.aspx</wfrm>
    </wbfrm>
    <wbfrm>
        <wfname>WebForm10</wfname>
        <wfrm>WebForm10.aspx</wfrm>
    </wbfrm>
    <wbfrm>
        <wfname>WebForm11</wfname>
        <wfrm>WebForm11.aspx</wfrm>
    </wbfrm>
    <wbfrm>
        <wfname>WebForm12</wfname>
        <wfrm>WebForm12.aspx</wfrm>
    </wbfrm>
</webformname>
```

And here is a code sample that I found which uses xmldoc and Linq except it only deals with one element.  How can I implement this code for my xml file which contains 2 elements?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

List<string> list = doc.Root.Elements("id")
                       .Select(element => element.Value)
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: What would a *single* string in the List look like with *two* values? - What is the desired output structure?

Comment: I just want to create a simple List<string, string> to use as a datasource for a gridview.  How would that look so that  I could use Linq -- with my xml file?

Comment: Use a dictionary : Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("wbfrm").GroupBy(x => (String)x.Element("wfname"), y => (String)y.Element("wfrm"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm being  lazy.  I came up with  this routine which I could create my list from -- just seems a little verbose.  Any suggestions for an improved way would be appreciated:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path + "wfXml.xml");

var wfrms = from r in doc.Descendants("wbfrm")
                    select new
                    {
                        Wfname = r.Element("wfname").Value,
                        Wfrm = r.Element("wfrm").Value
                    };

foreach (var m in wfrms)
{    
    Response.Write(string.Format( "{0}, {1} <br />", m.Wfname, m.Wfrm));
}
```

Then I could  populate my List --string, string -- or probably use wfrms as the datasource itself.